# Lost pixels during a raster merge with gdalbuildvrt

Tags: python, raster, gdal, merge, pixel

I'm trying to merge some rasters with gdalbuildvrt in a python script:

```
rasters = glob.glob('/{0}/ndvi_masked/*.tif'.format(path))

gdal_cmd = 'gdalbuildvrt -q -vrtnodata "0" -overwrite {0}.vrt'.format(ndvi_name)

for pix in rasters:
    gdal_cmd += ' {0}'.format(pix)

subprocess.call(gdal_cmd, shell=True)

gdal_cmd = 'gdal_translate -of GTiff %s.vrt  %s_clip.tif' % (ndvi_name, ndvi_name)

subprocess.call(gdal_cmd, shell=True)
```

But the result is really weird, cause I losted some pixels as you can see on the 2nde image below.

***All displayed rasters***
[image: All displayed rasters]

***Merge raster***
[image: Merge raster]

Comment: I tried with gdal_merge.py and the result is the same. Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: Could you share some small dataset for testing?

Comment: Perhaps you need to specify `-srcnodata` rather than `-vrtnodata`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution who works perfectly. I added this piece of code before my first code:

```
rasters = glob.glob('/{0}/ndvi_clip/*.tif'.format(path))

for pix in rasters:
    gdal_cmd = 'gdal_translate -a_nodata nan {0} {1}/{2}_{3}.tif'.format(pix, noNaN_path, ndvi_name, rasters.index(pix))
    subprocess.call(gdal_cmd, shell=True)
```

I don't know why, but nan values in my raster weren't real nodata.
With this command, I convert nan to nodata.

Here's the doc of this command: [gdal_translate](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)